# Command Prompt Stop, Wait, Start

Tags: cmd, wait, process.start

I would like a simple batch while that does the following

Stops a Service 
Wait 3 minutes 
Starts the Service

so I have

```
net stopMitral Tasks Service
net startMitral Tasks Service
timeout /t 180

net stopMitral Tasks Service
net startMitral Tasks Service
```

Would this work?

In terms of the Net stopService 
is that all that is need - no file path to the actual .exe?

Answer (score 1):

This will stop and then restart the service listed, wait 180 seconds and then repeat it.

```
net stop "Mitral Tasks Service"
net start "Mitral Tasks Service"
timeout /t 180 /nobreak
net stop "Mitral Tasks Service"
net start "Mitral Tasks Service"
```

Comment: Hi Foxbreak  <br/>
I need it to stop it, restart it straight away and then wait 180 seconds, then repeat  <br/> 

So would it be 

'net stop "Mitral Tasks Service"'
'net start "Mitral Tasks Service"'
'timeout /t 180 /nobreak'

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to make do Line Breaks and highlight code with adding comments 

The helpfile isn't very helpful